# All Salt Stack functions able to be set as variables?

Tags: timezone, jinja2, salt-stack

I erroneously thought that if you could run a function on the command line in SaltStack, that you could set that output as a variable. For example, consider the following which outputs the timezone of all minions:

`salt '*' timezone.get_zone`

It outputs a single string like `Etc/UTC` as the timezone. I am writing a function to run some cron jobs based on the timezone of the local server. However, in a jinja template, when I set:

```
...
{% set timezone = salt['timezone.get_zone'] %}

{% if timezone == 'America/Los_Angeles' %}
0 23 * * * root somecommand
{% else %}
# TIMEZONE NOT FOUND
{% endif %}
....
```

I always get the `# TIMEZONE NOT FOUND` output for that template. If I try to pass the timezone via `context` inside of the SLS file for the formula, I get the following after rendering:

`<function get_zone at 0x7fb48a7c9f50>`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<function get_zone at 0x7fb48a7c9f50>` is a clue.  `salt['timezone.get_zone']` is returning a function.  To actually call it, you need to put parens after it, so your line needs to look like:

`{% set timezone = salt['timezone.get_zone']() %}`

That should work for you.  It worked in my tests.

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually did try `('')` since I knew I might need to pass an empty string, but that threw an error.